# Incorrect syntax near else in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
USE [SocialNet]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_login]    Script Date: 5/6/2020 10:20:58 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_login](@flag int=0, @uid varchar(50)='', @fname varchar(50)='', @lname varchar(50)='',@email varchar(50)='', @address varchar(50)='',@city varchar(50)='',@country varchar(50)='',@phonenumber varchar(50)='', @gender char(10)='',@dob varchar(50)='', @photo varchar(50)='', @secques varchar(50)='',@secans varchar(50)='', @pswd varchar(50)='', @utype char(10)='',@status bit =0)
AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */
BEGIN
    if(@flag=0)
        select  userid  from login where userid=@uid;
    else
    if(@flag=1)
        insert into registration(userid, firstname, lastname, email, address, city,country, phonenumber, gender, dateofbirth, photo, securityquestion, securityanswer)
        values(@uid, @fname, @lname, @email, @address, @city, @country, @phonenumber, @gender, @dob, @photo, @secques, @secans)

        insert into login(userid, password, usertype,status) 
        values(@uid,@pswd,@utype,@status)

    else     
    if (@flag=2)
        select* from login where userid=@uid and password=@pswd and status=1;    
END
RETURN
```

I have this stored procedure, and I need to put another else if. But the last one I put it says incorrect syntax. Can you please help me with this? Thank you

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. You have 2 `ELSE` sections.

Comment: Looks like you have two `if`s, but only one `end`.

Comment: `IF` doesn't need an `END` with out a `BEGIN`, @Andrew . The `END` is for the `BEGIN` after the `AS`.

Comment: I want to add another else if, the last one. Can you please help me with te correct syntax?

Comment: You need to remove `;` from `select  userid  from login where userid=@uid;` and use a `BEGIN ... END` for the second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` allows only one statement to follow.  You have two, so the `else` is not recognized.

In T-SQL, I almost always put `begin`/`end` blocks to prevent such problems:

```
if @flag = 1
begin
    insert into registration(userid, firstname, lastname, email, address, city, country, phonenumber, gender, dateofbirth, photo, securityquestion, securityanswer) 
        values (@uid, @fname, @lname, @email, @address, @city, @country, @phonenumber, @gender, @dob, @photo, @secques, @secans);
    insert into login(userid, password, usertype, status) 
        values (@uid, @pswd, @utype, @status);
end;
else if @flag = 2
begin
    select l.*
    from login l
    where userid = @uid and password = @pswd and status = 1;
end;
```

Note that I put a `begin`/`end` block around the `else` statement as well.  If I ever add a new statement there (say for debugging or some other reason), then no worries.  Also, I've ended the statements with semicolons.